# are APM and EAP are obsolete now after .NET 4.5 is released?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

are APM (Asynchronous programming model) and EAP ( Event based asynchronous programming) are obsolete after the release of .net 4.5 and the current release of c# with TPL based async and await paradigm in VS2012?

Answer (score 2):

They're not obsolete, because you still need to use such patterns to support .NET 4 and lower applications. For .NET 4.5 though, it shouldn't be a question whether to use the new async features. Do it, because it's awesome.